# How to Include columns in select query based condtion

Tags: sql, oracle

Include the column only when the value is passed is > 0.

Below are example of the value passed and select query constructed/result to be returned:

| column1 | column2 |
| --- | --- |
| 10 | 12 |
| 11 | 12 |
| 10 | 13 |

Ex-1:
val_column1=0
val_column2=12
I need my query to be : `select * from table where column2=&val_column2;`

| column1 | column2 |
| --- | --- |
| 10 | 12 |
| 11 | 12 |

Ex-2:
val_column1=10
val_column2=12
I need my query to be : `select * from table where column1=&val_column1 and column2=&val_column2;`

| column1 | column2 |
| --- | --- |
| 10 | 12 |

Ex-3:
val_column1=10
val_column2=0
I need my query to be : `select * from table where column1=&val_column1;`

| column1 | column2 |
| --- | --- |
| 10 | 12 |
| 10 | 13 |

Comment: Please provide [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). What is the "value"? Are those columns always in a table or they should or may not exist depending on the "value"?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

That would be something like this, I presume:

```
select *
from your_table
where (column1 = &val_column1 or &val_column1 = 0)
  and (column2 = &val_column2 or &val_column2 = 0);
```